# PowerPoint: Edit filepath in image pasted as object link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, powerpoint, openxml, python-pptx

***Note:*** (not sure if I should put this here or on Super User)

I paste images into PowerPoints as a link, so that it updates when I update the source. Like this:

[image: Powerpoint paste as Excel link picture]

Usually, I update the image by modifying the original and then updating the link, like this:

[image: Powerpoint update linked picture]

However, if I open it from another computer, it can't update the link because it can't find the file. I'm assuming because it uses an absolute filepath and my file is in a Dropbox-like system, so the `%USERPROFILE%` part of the path (like `JohnDoe` in `C:\Users\JohnDoe\Dropbox`) is different for each computer.

So I thought I could search the OOXML version of the file to see that filepath and then modify it on my own. However, I tried searching it with Python and BeautifulSoup4, but couldn't find anything.

Any idea how I can modify or find this path to the linked object?

**UPDATE:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49561446/6067848)
 answer, it worked! really helped me, thanks.